# MongoDB Java Driver Array

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to save a set of tags within a mongodb document e.g.

```
{
    id:"104454",
    tags:["tag1", "tag2"]
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how to do this with the Java Driver though. I thought I would use `BasicDBList` but this doesnt seem to be right.

Could someone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial

Comment: I have already read through this but as far as I can see it doesn't show how to create JSON arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple arrays and then you can do something like:

```
doc.put("tags", array)
```

Answer (score 3):

When saving arrays into MongoDB with Java, according to the [online doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types#JavaTypes-Arrays), you can use anything that extends `List`.

So, using your example, that would be something like the following:

```
ArrayList tags = new ArrayList();
tags.add("tag1");
tags.add("tag2");

BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject(new ObjectId(), tags);
```